Can I setup my OpenVPN home server on port 123 udp?
Considering that many public networks block most outgoing udp ports, I'd like to ask if I can setup my OpenVPN server on port 123 udp (used by windows ntp server).
I've noticed that many public networks do not block the windows ntp server port, so I'd like to utilize it for my OpenVPN server to access my home network.
The OpenVPN server is hosted on synology NAS which runs on linux. The port forwarding would only be realized for the synology NAS and none of the other devices on my home network.
Does this approach incur any security issues or problems that may arise in the future?

You can set up OpenVPN on any UDP port number you like, it doesn't care; but

it might break Synology's own NTP access, depending on which NTP software it uses, because an often-used NTP "symmetric" mode actually uses ports '123→123' instead of the typical 'random→123' (Windows NTP client is one example but I've seen this on Linux as well).
If the Synology NTP client uses the "client-server" mode (i.e. using a random local port number), it should be fine to coexist with your VPN server.

there are actually networks that specifically block inbound UDP 123 because it's NTP. (In part as a precaution because of the last year's 'ntpd' bugs that turned many unmaintained NTP servers into DDoS reflectors.)
In theory only inbound 'any→123' should be blocked, but don't count on all network admins writing precise enough rules; some places just block it in all directions, so even if your home ISP doesn't block it inbound, you might come across places that block it outbound.



(And in general, for every "popular" protocol that seems like it'd be permitted everywhere, there's always a sysadmin who will block it deliberately. DNS on port 53? Lots of places block or intercept it. QUIC on port 443? Seen multiple admins wage wars against it.)
